# Habitual past vs simple past

Tags: translation, english-to-german, tense

How would the translation of the habitual past

> He would visit the beach everyday

differ from the one of the simple past

> He visited the beach everyday?

when translating those sentences to German?

Answer (score 8):

Of course, the simple past can be translated as

> Er ging jeden Tag zum Strand.

Expressing the habitual past isn't that easy. You can use the verb "pflegen" to express the habitual aspect:

> Er pflegte jeden Tag zum Strand zu gehen.

However, this is quite elevated style; you wouldn't normally *say* that, it rather fits into a novel.

As an alternative, you could explicitly talk about the habit, like

> Es war seine Gewohnheit, jeden Tag zum Strand zu gehen.

or

> Er hatte die Angewohnheit, jeden Tag zum Strand zu gehen.

Again, this is for written conversation. I think in everyday speech you would just use the simple past, except for the cases where you could employ "immer" as suggested by Emanuel.

Comment: +1 for "pflegen zu". Completely forgot about that one.

Comment: Pflegen is the normal everyday word in Yiddish for habitual pased (= "used to" in Englsih).

Answer (score 6):

One very common way to talk about habits is the word "immer".

> Thomas hat sich immer selber Essen mitgebracht.
>   Thomas would bring his own food all the time.

However, that doesn't work if it's only an occasional habit or (as in your example) if there is a second, more specific indication of time.

> Ich bin **immer jeden Tag** zum Strand gegangen... sounds odd to me.

Generally, German doesn't make too much of an effort in making a distinction.

> Thomas ist oft zum Strand gegangen.

This can be just pure information about how frequently he did go as well as a description of his habits. It's up to context what comes across. If you really feel like you need to underline the habit you'd have to make a sentence about that.

> Thomas hatte die Angewohnheit, jeden Tag zum Strand zu gehen.

That sounds already quite scripted though and you won't hear this in spoken German all that much.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the `would` puts emphasis on the temporary nature and the start of the habit. The best translation for this I can think of is

> Er hatte es sich zur Gewohnheit gemacht, jeden Tag an den Strand zu gehen.

or

> Er hatte sich angewöhnt, jeden Tag an den Strand zu gehen.

This stresses the temporary nature better than `Er hatte die Angewohnheit / Es war seine Gewohnheit`, which makes it sound as if the habit has always been there.